# Create custom customer attribute magento2

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute

I am trying to create custom attribute for customer , but it is not creating anything i cannot able to view in admin

here is my code

```
<?php

namespace Test\Hd\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\AttributeRepository;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;


class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @var Config
     */
    private $eavConfig;

    /**
     * @var
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory) 
    {
       $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
       $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

   /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
    */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'fin_cus', [
            'type'         => 'varchar',
                'label'        => 'Fin customer',
                'input'        => 'text',
                'required'     => false,
                'visible'      => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'position'     => 999,
                'system'       => 0,
         ]);

         $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'fin_cus')
            ->addData([
                 'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                 'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                 'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
          ]);

         $attribute->save();
}
```

but i don't find any custom attribute in admin created ,Kindly

Comment: check in eav_attribute table that attribute is created or not. Also mention your magento version in question.

Comment: You can use logging in the install script to check what happens, however, if I had to guess, I'd say you had this module installed prior to creating the InstallData (i.e. there has been a record for this module in `setup_module` table already). InstallData will be executed exactly once, which is while actually installing the module. In that case you must create an upgrade script.

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this one

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Custom\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, Config $eavConfig)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig       = $eavConfig;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'sample_attribute',
            [
                'type'         => 'varchar',
                'label'        => 'Sample Attribute',
                'input'        => 'text',
                'required'     => false,
                'visible'      => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'position'     => 999,
                'system'       => 0,
            ]
        );
        $sampleAttribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'sample_attribute');

        // more used_in_forms ['adminhtml_checkout','adminhtml_customer','adminhtml_customer_address','customer_account_edit','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address']
        $sampleAttribute->setData(
            'used_in_forms',
            ['adminhtml_customer']

        );
        $sampleAttribute->save();
    }
}
```

Now, Run command line to install the module:

> php magento setup:upgrade

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Then check the result. It will show like this:
[image]